# What are the first bytes in the input to getTransaction?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Code -

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;

contract CA15 {

struct Student {
        uint16 age;
    uint16 income;
    uint16 score;
    uint16 attendance;
}

Student[] public students;
function setStudent (uint16 _age, uint16 _income, uint16 _score, uint16 _attendance) public {
   Student memory tempStudent = Student({age: _age, income: _income, score: _score, attendance: _attendance});
        students.push(tempStudent);
}

}
```

Output -

```
> con.setStudent(21, 18000, 5, 94)
"0x855c891d8c1e06cc5a82c3d3922cdca9fae456ed9f9ebcdc528c9cb5d9d7c07f"
> eth.getTransaction("0x855c891d8c1e06cc5a82c3d3922cdca9fae456ed9f9ebcdc528c9cb5d9d7c07f")
{
  blockHash: "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  blockNumber: null,
  from: "0x46fb9a22689c4a4bfb494baeafbb8b2993725305",
  gas: 90000,
  gasPrice: 100000000000,
  hash: "0x855c891d8c1e06cc5a82c3d3922cdca9fae456ed9f9ebcdc528c9cb5d9d7c07f",
  input: "0x1b0a52cc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005e",
  nonce: 305,
  r: "0xae48d8444ac2804d6552e46849a6c1bb057910a5216a3c1af648292ece9fcb6e",
  s: "0x227bf70080d795455a820f424de1ad152fee5d85aeb0e4fb0463563fc68d457d",
  to: "0x755733df85f60e43a70880def295bec58be41cc6",
  transactionIndex: 0,
  v: "0x2b694",
  value: 0
}
```

This is the input -

input: `"0x1b0a52cc000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000046500000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005e",`

1. Why is uint used and not uint16 in the txn input?
2. What is this - `1b0a52cc`?

Contract address -

```
0x755733df85f60e43a70880def295bec58be41cc6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/abi-spec.html answers both questions.

The first four bytes are the function selector: the first four bytes of the keccak256 hash of the function signature. You can reproduce it like this:

```
web3.sha3('setStudent(uint16,uint16,uint16,uint16)').substr(0, 10);
```

ABI encoding uses 32-byte lengths for pretty much anything.

Comment: I get the 4 bytes now but the docs state uint16 is supported. Why is uint used in the parameter list for the function? That seems inefficient to me. Would is not be better to pass only two bytes per variable?

Comment: I don't know the reasoning behind the ABI design. I was just trying to answer the question of why you see 32-byte values rather than the 2-byte values you expected.

Comment: I get that, I guess this is a classic "how" versus "why." It does process 32 bytes for a two byte field apparently. So I saw something about EVMs prefer 32 bytes due to swapping and maybe that is the reason.